# Is there any way to export changed tags and css styling from chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When I work on my project it is my habit that I save my document and refresh the browser to see any change which is a time consuming task. Even sometimes I make changes directly in the chrome using devtools according to my needs and in the end do the same in project IDE.

My question is that can I do my whole work in chrome and later export the whole HTML and CSS styling as a project/raw text? OR at-least export the the changes I have made using chrome?

I know it seems a stupid question because we have a lot of great features in our latest IDEs but the reason I want to do this is the live changes I can see in chrome without any delay, there is no need to save, open the browser and refresh to see the commited changes :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature of Dev Tools called Workspaces.

It maps remote resources you're tweaking in it to local files and persists changes.

Here's the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow).

It's not a miracle cure though:

> As powerful as Workspaces are, there are some limitations you should be aware of.
>
> - Only style changes in the Elements panel are persisted; changes to the DOM are not persisted.
> - Only styles defined in an external CSS file can be saved. Changes to element.style or to inline styles are not persisted. (If you have inline styles, they can be changed on the Sources panel.)
> - Style changes in the Elements panel are persisted immediately without an explicit save -- Ctrl + S or Cmd + S (Mac) -- if you have the CSS resource mapped to a local file.
> - If you are mapping files from a remote server instead of a local server, when you refresh the page, Chrome reloads the page from the remote server. Your changes still persist to disk and are reapplied if you continue editing in Workspaces.
> - You must use the full path to a mapped file in the browser. Even your index files must include .html in the URL, in order to see the staged version.